# Row editing for table using mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am generating an HTML table from a database. I want to be able to edit rows in the table to update the data each row represents. Here is how my table looks:

```
<table id="studenttable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ClassId</th>
            <th>StudentId</th>
            <th>ClassName</th>
            <th>StudentName</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th colspan="3">process</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr class="studenttable1">

                <td id="tdclassid.classid">
                    @Html.TextBox("classid", @item.classid, new { id = "txtclassid", @readonly = "readonly" })
                </td>

                <td id="tdstudentid">
                    @Html.TextBox("studentid", @item.studentid, new { id="txtstudentid", @readonly="readonly" })
                </td>

                <td id="tdclassname">
                    @Html.TextBox("classnama", @item.studentname, new { id="txtclassname",@readonly="readonly"})
                </td>

                <td id="tdstudentname">
                    @Html.TextBox("studentname", @item.classname, new { id="txtstudentname", @readonly="readonly" })                    
                </td>

                <td id="tdaddress">
                    @Html.TextBox("address", @item.address, new { id="txtaddress", @readonly="readonly" })
                </td>

                <td class="tdedit">
                    <a href="#" id="anchoredit" onclick="insertRowq()">edit</a>  |
                    <a href="#" id="anchordelete" onclick="insertRowq()">done</a>
                </td>

                <td id="tddetails">
                     @Html.ActionLink("details", "Index", null, null, new { @class = "actdetails" })
                </td>

            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use jQuery to make the text inputs editable when you click the edit button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#anchoredit').click(function () {

        $('#txtclassid').attr("readonly", false);
        $('#txtstudentid').attr("readonly", false);
        $('#txtclassname').attr("readonly", false);        
        $('#txtstudentname').attr("readonly", false);
        $('#txtaddress').attr("readonly", false);

        $('#txtclassid').addClass("addclassid");
        $('#txtstudentid').addClass("addclassid");
        $('#txtclassname').addClass("addclassid");
        $('#txtstudentname').addClass("addclassid");
        $('#txtaddress').addClass("addclassid");

    });
});
```

### Output

[image: A table with six columns, the first five containing a disabled text input and the last containing links to edit or delete the row.]

I bind the data in table using a `foreach` loop, but this only works for the first row; if I click the second row it doesn't work. Where might I be going wrong, and how can I make this work like I would like it to?

Comment: yep, second row not processed because jquery id selector returns first from elements with same id. try use class instead of id for selecting with specify row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need specify row and I think it would be better to use a class instead of id something like this in js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.anchoredit').click(function () {
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        row.find('.yourtextboxclass').attr("readonly", false).addClass("addclassid");
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.anchoredit').click(function () {
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        row.find('input').attr("readonly", false).addClass("addclassid");
    });
});
```

also you must change in Html that create TextBoxt with class instead of id or with id

**UPDATE**
for hide previous
since you did not save the value before editing next varian simply disable edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.anchoredit').click(function () {
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();
        var table = row.parent();
        table.find('input.addclassid').removeClass(".addclassid").attr("readonly", true)
        row.find('input').attr("readonly", false).addClass("addclassid");
    });
});
```

but this variant does not return value that was befor editing

Comment: row is jquery object corresponding to the `tr`, so its `toString()` return `"[object,object]"`. How you try check it?

Comment: This second jquery working fine Grundy. How to hide my previous inline editable process

Comment: @dinesh.k more questions? :-)